# Normalization of a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, scikit-learn, normalization

I have a 150x4 matrix `X` which I created from a pandas dataframe using the following code:

```
X = df_new.as_matrix()
```

I have to normalize it using this function:

[image: this]

I know that `Uj` is the mean val of `j`, and that `σ j` is the standard deviation of `j`, but I don't understand what `j` is. I'm having a little trouble understanding what the bar on `X` is, and I'm confused by the commas in the equation (I don't know if they have any significance or not).

Can anyone help me understand what this equation means so I can then write the normalization using sklearn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need to write code for the normalization yourself - it comes ready with [`sklearn.preprocessing.scale`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html).

Here is an example [from the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing-scaler):

```
>>> from sklearn import preprocessing
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
...                     [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
...                     [ 0.,  1., -1.]])
>>> X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X_train)

>>> X_scaled                                          
array([[ 0.  ..., -1.22...,  1.33...],
       [ 1.22...,  0.  ..., -0.26...],
       [-1.22...,  1.22..., -1.06...]])
```

When used with the default setting `axis=0`, the mormalization happens column-wise (i.e. for each column `j`, as in your equestion). As a result, it is easy to confirm that scaled data has zero mean and unit variance:

```
>>> X_scaled.mean(axis=0)
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])

>>> X_scaled.std(axis=0)
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Comment: Oh wow cool! For clarification, in this scenario could I just apply my `X` where you have `X_train`? Furthermore, would you be able to explain the equation a little? I understand that the code you've provided does essentially that, but I want to be able to read the equation too

Comment: @tushariyer Was ready to do this, but essentially what @maxim-egorushkin has written is all. In your case, `j` in the equation goes from 0 to 3 (4 columns), and the mean & variance is per column `j`.

Comment: Gotcha, it's clearer to me now that I have read both your responses. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @tushariyer you are very welcome; thanks for upvoting, now kindly select one answer and mark it as correct/accepted...

Answer (score 1):

The indexes for matrix X are row (i) and column (j). Hence, `X,j` means column `j` of matrix `X`. I.e. normalize each column of matrix X to [z-scores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score).

You can do that using pandas:

```
df_new_zscores = (df_new - df_new.mean()) / df_new.std()
```

Comment: I think I get it? There are four columns, so `j` refers to them all? Could you explain a little more as to what the normalization does? I appreciate the help, but I want to understand what it is so I can learn better. Furthermore, this makes it a dataframe again, what if I wanted to keep it as a matrix/numpy array?

Comment: @tushariyer `j` refers to _any_ column. This is what normalization does: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score

Answer (score 1):

I do not know pandas but I think that the equation means that the normalized matrix is given by
[image]
You subtract the empirical mean and devide by the empirical standard deviation per column.

You sometimes use this for Principal Component Analysis.